# how to prevent windows form design from being cluttered when it is viewed everytime?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I design the window forms on visual studio, and I saved it to keep my changes.But unfortunately on every time I look for something on desing view, everything gets cluttered. Is there any tip to keep it tidy ?

** lock items does not work for it. Whatver it does itself, on every preview, it gets messy!

Comment: This shouldn't happen. When you design a form all the items are locked to where they were placed.

Comment: What does the code in your form's constructor look like?

Comment: Perhaps you have something corrupt as well in the Designer.cs file for that form.. can you try closing VS and re-opening it.. if worse comes to worse.. start a new project and then add a new existing item an select the old form to see if that would change or cleanup the issue..also if you have code.. post that so that perhaps someone can visually spot any errors or adnormal behavior..